# PHP и работа с длинной арифметикой

Tags: php

```
var_dump(bcadd('0.0000000001', '0.000000002'));
```

Результат:

```
string(1) "0"
```

Вопрос: какая есть готовая библиотека для сложения, вычитания, умножения, деления длинных чисел?

Comment: [var_dump(bcadd('0.0000000001', '0.000000002', 10));](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.bcadd.php)

Comment: @Ипатьев, а если необходимая точность заранее неизвестна? `var_dump(rtrim(bcadd('0.0000000001', '0.000000002', 200), '0'));`?

Answer (score 2):

Функция `bcadd` принимает 3-й параметр, который называется `scale`

> Этот необязательный параметр используется для установки количества знаков после десятичного разделителя в результате. Если не задано, то, по умолчанию, будет использовано значение заданное глобально с помощью bcscale(), либо 0.

Укажите его, к примеру, равным 10

`var_dump(bcadd('0.0000000001', '0.000000002', 10));`

Результат

`string(12) "0.0000000021"`